# awk lines to multiple columns

Tags: awk, multiple-columns, transformation, lines

Input text to get lines alligned is in this format

(LINE_A) is name of file e.g. LINE_A placed in directory xy
inside of that file is

```
file:G_VALUEFX:D_VALUEFX;SEAT01
```

which is returning

this

```
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
```

(number in 1st column is returned count of total columns on line)

and i need help with this lines to transform them from this lines

e.g.

```
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 SEAT30      
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 SEAT30
```

to columns

```
7 LINE_A    7 LINE_B    7 LINE_A     7 LINE_B 
G_VALUEFX   G_VALUEFX   G_VALUEFA    G_VALUEFA 
D_VALUEFX   D_VALUEFX   D_VALUEFA    D_VALUEFA 
SEAT01      SEAT22      SEAT01       SEAT22 
SEAT02      SEAT25      SEAT02       SEAT25 
SEAT03      SEAT27      SEAT03       SEAT27 
SEAT04      SEAT30      SEAT04       SEAT30
```

( i am not sure if its possible to transform it to this the way that columns are aligned like this way)

```
7 LINE_A   |  7 LINE_B   | 7 LINE_A   |  7 LINE_B 
G_VALUEFX  |  G_VALUEFX  | G_VALUEFA  |  G_VALUEFA 
D_VALUEFX  |  D_VALUEFX  | D_VALUEFA  |  D_VALUEFA 
SEAT01     |  SEAT22     | SEAT01     |  SEAT22 
SEAT02     |  SEAT25     | SEAT02     |  SEAT25 
SEAT03     |  SEAT27     | SEAT03     |  SEAT27 
SEAT04     |  SEAT30     | SEAT04     |  SEAT30
```

it can happen that some lines should be longer and shorter e.g.

```
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 SEAT30      
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8    
7 LINE_C G_PREFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
8 LINE_G G_PREFX D_VALUEFX POSITION55 POSITION82 VALUE85 POSITION44 POSITION448
7 LINE_C G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03       
4 LINE_H G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22
5 LINE_H G_NAMEA D_EXPIRY5 SEAT01 SEAT02 
3 LINE_H G_NAMEA D_EXPIRY5 
7 LINE_B G_NAMEY D_EXPIRY1 SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
```

and output then might look like this ( with number of lines given = more columns aligned / placed to each other) if possible with column separator "|"
all the time there should be first placed number with LINE_A/B  2nd followed by G prefix ; 3rd D prefix rest are values with random info
(if its more convenient there should not be number before "LINE_A/B" included )

```
7 LINE_A    7 LINE_B     7 LINE_A      7 LINE_B                    7 LINE_C  8 LINE_G     7 LINE_C   4 LINE_H   5 LINE_H   3 LINE_H  7 LINE_B 
G_VALUEFX   G_VALUEFX    G_VALUEFA     G_VALUEFA                   G_PREFX   G_PREFX      G_PREFA    G_PREFA    G_NAMEA    G_NAMEA   G_NAMEY 
D_VALUEFX   D_VALUEFX    D_VALUEFA     D_VALUEFA                   D_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX    D_VALUEFA  D_VALUEFA  D_EXPIRY5  D_EXPIRY5 D_EXPIRY1
SEAT01      SEAT22       SEAT01        SEAT22                      SEAT01    POSITION55   SEAT01     SEAT22     SEAT01               SEAT22 
SEAT02      SEAT25       SEAT02        SEAT25                      SEAT02    POSITION82   SEAT02                SEAT02               SEAT25 
SEAT03      SEAT27       SEAT03        SEAT27                      SEAT03    VALUE85      SEAT03                                     SEAT27 
SEAT04      SEAT30       SEAT04        EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8   SEAT04    POSITION44                                              EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 
                                                                             POSITION448
```

Thank you

Comment: It's perfectly doable, but somewhat fiddly. You have to read the whole file into memory — the last line could contain the most fields and the widest fields, and until you've read it, you won't know how big the output needs to be. For the rest, you need to keep a record of the widest value in each line of input as that will control the width of the corresponding column. Then you need to arrange your printing controls using `printf()` and `%.*s` where the `*` means 'width specified by integer'.  `printf("%.*s", width[colno], data[colno,lineno])` or thereabouts. You can produce the vertical bars.

Comment: You seem to have several different text blocks that all represent sample input in different ways (e.g. `file:G_VALUEFX:D_VALUEFX;SEAT01` vs `7 LINE_A G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04` and with different contents. It's not clear to me if you're telling us you have 1 input file (e.g. one file containing LINE_A, LINE_B, etc) or many (files **named** LINE_A, LINE_B, etc.). Please [edit] your question to show **the** sample input (if it's multiple files then show that) that you want to transform to your posted expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton: The OP has shown two sample inputs and the corresponding expected outputs — that's a good effort.  There isn't any evidence of having tried to produce a program to solve the problem (no MCVE — [MCVE]), but they have shown good expected input and output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what are the sample inputs? Is a file named LINE_A containing `file:G_VALUEFX:D_VALUEFX;SEAT01` a sample input file? If so - what is `7 LINE_A G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04 `, If not - what is it? I feel like the OP may have some tool that's converting a bunch of files in the first format to one file in the 2nd format as some kind of intermediate and almost certainly unnecessary step but I really don't know so I'm hoping the OP will clarify and show us.

Comment: @EdMorton: OK — I skipped over the line with `file:…` — that seems to be a red herring compared to the other sources of input.  But I'll have to agree that there is room for confusion.

Comment: In your format with vertical bars, sometimes you have two spaces, sometimes you have one space after the vertical bars.  You'll need to be consistent — or explain how the number of spaces is chosen (but consistency is easier).  Likewise, you should say how many spaces before the vertical bar.  It appears to be 2 (or more if the field is narrow).  In which case, 2 after the bar makes consistent sense too.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @EdMorton Hi, files are named  LINE_A, LINE_B, etc.; yes inside of file is eg. file:G_VALUEFX:D_VALUEFX;SEAT01 line by line, and many others its only mentioned structure of file, how it looks inside with one line as example showed. 

then its transformed to that example i presented: eg.
e.g.
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 SEAT30      

with expected output with multiple columns (variations in value lenght) for that first 2 i am using :

Comment: cat LINE_A | awk '{print FILENAME$0}' *_* | grep 'file' | sed 's/file:/ /g; s/:/ /g; s/;/ /g' | sort -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 | awk -F ' ' '{print NF " "$0 }' | awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^G_/) {t=$i;$i=$4;$4=t;break}} 1'

returning:
5 LINE_A G_NAMEA D_EXPIRY5 SEAT01 SEAT02
3 LINE_A G_NAMEA D_EXPIRY5
7 LINE_A G_NAMEY D_EXPIRY1 SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
6 LINE_A G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03

but not sure if sed is possible somehow replace as well
,i am still assuming that sed is good for this "cutting" operations good or isnt it? as well with using cat/grep

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , posted above what i tried, i dont know as well how to replace cat as its need to read to memory > then grep > then processing with sed and awk, its performing then quite bad that query, cat should read in loop or do it somehow via awk thru multiple files passed via variable ? i am here a bit lost too with further processing to latest expected format

Comment: @ya801: as the asker of the question, you can — and should — update the question with extra information so that it is readable and formatted. (You can't format it much in comments, as you can now see.) You can replace `cat LINE_A | awk '…program…' | …` with `awk '…program…' LINE_A | …` as `awk` will read the files named on its command line. In a general script, you might replace `LINE_A` with `"$@"` (the arguments to the shell script). —— Are you pre-formatting data from the `file:G_VALUEFX:D_VALUEFX;SEAT01` notation into the `7 LINE_A G_VALUEFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04` notation?

Comment: @ya801 you don't all those different tools and pipes, you don't need to transform your files first, you never need sed or grep when you're using awk, etc... If you post a new question with your original input files and final expected output we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS=' | ' '{a[NR,1]=$1 FS $2; 
                     for(j=3;j<=NF;j++) a[NR,j-1]=$j; 
                     maxNF=maxNF<NF?NF:maxNF}
                END {for(i=1;i<maxNF;i++)
                       for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)
                          printf "%s",a[j,i] (j==NR?ORS:OFS)}' file | column -ts'|'

7 LINE_A     7 LINE_B     7 LINE_A     7 LINE_B                     7 LINE_C     8 LINE_G       7 LINE_C     4 LINE_H     5 LINE_H     3 LINE_H     7 LINE_B
G_VALUEFX    G_VALUEFX    G_VALUEFA    G_VALUEFA                    G_PREFX      G_PREFX        G_PREFA      G_PREFA      G_NAMEA      G_NAMEA      G_NAMEY
D_VALUEFX    D_VALUEFX    D_VALUEFA    D_VALUEFA                    D_VALUEFX    D_VALUEFX      D_VALUEFA    D_VALUEFA    D_EXPIRY5    D_EXPIRY5    D_EXPIRY1
SEAT01       SEAT22       SEAT01       SEAT22                       SEAT01       POSITION55     SEAT01       SEAT22       SEAT01                    SEAT22
SEAT02       SEAT25       SEAT02       SEAT25                       SEAT02       POSITION82     SEAT02                    SEAT02                    SEAT25
SEAT03       SEAT27       SEAT03       SEAT27                       SEAT03       VALUE85        SEAT03                                              SEAT27
SEAT04       SEAT30       SEAT04       EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8    SEAT04       POSITION44                                                         EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
                                                                                 POSITION448
```

if you remove the piped `column` formatter, the output will be delimited with the pipe chars (but not aligned).

Comment: thank you added there too "sed  's/\r//'" to avoid wrong formating output  to make it unix style format, or its possible to replace by awk? found this several examples like: sub(/\r/,"") but not sure where to  put in that query or call it via another piped awk  query? , generally is it piping good thru multiple awk piped queries ?

Comment: @ya801: You should convert the input to Unix format before you start processing; keeping the carriage returns confuses everything.  There is a `dos2unix` command that will do it; you can also use `tr` for the job, or some versions of `sed` (and you could use Perl, Python, … or write your own, though that's probably not a good idea).  Just as Windows code gets upset by Unix line endings, Unix code gets upset (differently) by Windows line endings.  Make sure you're working with clean data for the system you're on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler hi , i am doing this already by `sed  's/\r//' | awk..` but again i am calling with new process created "sed" if i will pipe it not sure if awk piped with awk or sed piped with awk or then by cat will be threated as new process to make it in result on big file ,performance problem in processing file thats for me concern

Comment: What's a big file?  If you're converting to columnar form like this, a thousand columns with, judging from your examples, up to about a dozen column values, would be pretty large.  And that would be using a megabyte or so of data.  That isn't going to give processing problems on modern equipment — it isn't going to be a major problem on most antiques, even.  Demonstrate that you have a performance problem before worrying about it.  The pipeline in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491869/awk-lines-to-multiple-columns?noredirect=1#comment88006632_50491869) should be reducible.